# ActiveRecord conditional query with Dates not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
irb(main):104:0> s = Status.all
=> [#<Status id: 1, card_id: 1, user_id: 1, next: "2001-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1,          created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Status id: 2, card_id: 2, user_id: 1, next: "2001-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Status id: 3, card_id: 3, user_id: 1, next: "2011-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
irb(main):105:0> s[2].next < Time.now
=> false
irb(main):106:0> s[1].next < Time.now
=> true
irb(main):107:0> Status.where("next < ?", Time.now)
=> [#<Status id: 1, card_id: 1, user_id: 1, next: "2001-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Status id: 2, card_id: 2, user_id: 1, next: "2001-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, #<Status id: 3, card_id: 3, user_id: 1, next: "2011-01-01 00:00:00", level: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

I would expect the Status.where statement to only return 2 objects. It seems like the less than condition in the where clause is not working. If I switch it to an greater than, the query returns [].

next is set up as a datetime in the migration

Why is this conditional where query not working?
Thanks

Comment: Try to change Time.now to Time.now.utc

Answer (score 0):

You're right that this should work, assuming the database server has the correct time. What kind of database are you querying? Please update your question with that and the query generated by the .where() method.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should try to force DB formating in your query : `Time.now.to_s(:db)`

If it doesn't work, using a time zone could be a good idea.

```
Time.zone.now.to_s(:db)
```